# Android project. Setup Firebase AND Google Analytics

Tags: android, ios, firebase, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I have a iOS project with Google analytics and Firebase. (I log custom event in google analytics)

Now I want to do similar for an Android project.

**Question:**  Is there a way to set Google Analytics and Firebase in the same Android Studio projects. (I know I can "bind" Google Analytics to Firebase, but what I need is to log custom event in the same Google Analytics project that I use in iOS

Answer (score 0):

I found the perfect solution.

1-Follow theses steps:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/

2-Forget about the .json, just replace line:

> mTracker = analytics.newTracker(R.xml.global_tracker);

By:

```
    sTracker = sAnalytics.newTracker("UA-78965956-1");
```